# Template class for an Entity Component System library

Tags: c++, template, library, entity-component-system

I'm working on an Entity Component System library. Right know I'm trying to clean up the Entity/Component part (only the code which manage the data).

But I have a class which I think is not really readable. Maybe the implementation can be improved too, but I reduced the implementation to be small and fast, so it's not really why I'm here (but every review is always welcome).

**DefaultManager.hpp:**

```
#ifndef  DEFAULT_MANAGER_HPP
#define  DEFAULT_MANAGER_HPP

#include  "Defines.hpp"
#include  "HandleEntry.hpp"

#include  <cstddef>
#include  <vector>
#include  <type_traits>

//!
//! @namespace ECS
//!
namespace  ECS {

  //!
  //! @class DefaultManager
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  class  DefaultManager {

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Allow iterator to access the Pool
    template < ECS_INT Filter >
    friend class iterator;

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! GoogleTest Define
#ifdef  UTESTS
  #include "DefaultManager.utests"
#endif
    //-----------------------------------------


    private:
      static const size_t  BASE_SIZE = 1024;

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Internal Structs
    private:
      struct ObjectPair {

        std::conditional_t<Shared,
                           HandleEntryShared,
                           HandleEntry>  entry;
        Object  data;
      };

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Attributs
    protected:
      std::vector<ObjectPair>  m_pool;
      ECS_INT                  m_activeEntryCount;
      ECS_INT                  m_firstFreeEntry;


    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Iterator
    public:
      //! TODO: Need specialization for Filter = 0 (just remove the check on the filter)
      template < ECS_INT Filter = 0 >

      class iterator {

        private:
          size_t                           m_index;
          DefaultManager<Object, Shared>&  m_manager;

        public:
          using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;
          using size_type         = size_t;
          using value_type        = Object;
          using pointer           = Object*;
          using const_pointer     = const Object*;
          using reference         = Object&;
          using const_reference   = const Object&;

          using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;

          iterator(DefaultManager<Object, Shared>& manager,
                   size_t index = 0)
            : m_index(index),
              m_manager(manager)
          {}

          iterator& operator++() { while(!isValid()) ++m_index; return *this;}
          iterator& operator++(int) { iterator it = *this; ++(*this); return it;}
          iterator& operator--() { while(!isValid()) --m_index; return *this;}
          iterator& operator--(int) { iterator it = *this; --(*this); return it;}
          bool operator==(iterator other) const {return &m_pool[m_index] == &other.m_pool[m_index];}
          bool operator!=(iterator other) const {return !(*this == other);}
          reference operator*() { return m_manager.m_pool[m_index].data; }

          bool isValid() const {
            Object& obj = m_manager.m_pool[m_index].data;
            return (obj.type() & Filter) == obj.type();
          }
      };


      template < ECS_INT Filter = 0 >
      iterator<Filter>       begin();
      template < ECS_INT Filter = 0 >
      const iterator<Filter> cbegin() { return begin<Filter>(); }

      template < ECS_INT Filter = 0 >
      iterator<Filter>       end();
      template < ECS_INT Filter = 0 >
      const iterator<Filter> cend() { return end<Filter>(); }

    //-----------------------------------------

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Constructors
    public:
      DefaultManager(size_t allocSize = BASE_SIZE)
        : m_pool(allocSize),
          m_activeEntryCount(0),
          m_firstFreeEntry(0) {
      }

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Getters and Setters
    public:
      Object&  getObject(const ECS_INT index) {
        return m_pool[index].data;
      }

    //-----------------------------------------
    //! Functions
    protected:
      //!
      //! @brief Used by the manager to extend the pool when it's needed
      //!
      //! Add + BASIC_SIZE to the current pool capacity
      //! Copy current data into the new pool and init the new HandleEntry
      //!
      void  extendPool();

      //! @brief Primitive function used by the manager to release the data from one pool entry
      //!
      //! Put the activate bit to false for the pool entry whose index is specified as a parameter
      //! Update the manager firstFreeEntry, depend on the data released position
      //!
      //! @param index the index where the data to release is positionned.
      void  releaseObject(const ECS_INT index);

    public:
      //! @brief Specifie to the manager the need to reserve some memory space
      //!
      //! Use std::vector.resize() to reserve memory for the pool
      //! Initialize HandleEntry for every ObjectPair reserved
      //!
      //! @warning if you attempt do to so for every DefaultManager, think about change BASIC_SIZE
      //! @param allocSize the size to reserve in bytes
      void  reserveObjectMemory(size_t allocSize);

      //!
      //! @warning Don't use, not sure to be keep
      //!
      void  reset(size_t allocSize = BASE_SIZE);

      //!
      //! @brief Ask the manager to give a data segment from the pool
      //!
      //! Check if the pool has enough memory left (extend if not)
      //! Take the first free entry of the pool and activate the entry
      //! Initialize the data with args
      //!
      //! @param args pack of arguments you need to initialize your Object
      //! @return the index of the activated object
      template < typename ... Args >
      ECS_INT  addNewObject(Args && ... args);

      //!
      //! @brief Ask the manager to assign the object given to another entity
      //!
      //! Just increment the assigned counter of the HandleEntry which correspond
      //!
      //! @warning this function need the Shared from DefaultManager<typename Object, bool Shared> to be true
      //! @param index the index of the already added Object
      void  assignExistingObject(const ECS_INT index);

      //!
      //! @biref Remove need to be called when an entity revoke her access to an Object
      //!
      //! Depend on Shared value
      //! if Shared == true --> Will decrement the assigned counter and if the counter reach zero, release the memory
      //! if Shared == false --> Will just release the memory of the Object selected
      //!
      //! @param index the index of the data that you want remove
      void  removeObject(const ECS_INT index);
  };
}
#include  "DefaultManager.tpp"
#endif
```

**DefaultManager.tpp:**

```
namespace  ECS {

#define TEMPLATE_ARGS  typename Object, \
                       bool Shared

#define CLASS    DefaultManager<Object, Shared>
#define ITERATOR CLASS::iterator<Filter>

  //! Iterator
  //!------------------------------------------

  //!
  //! Begin
  //!
  template < TEMPLATE_ARGS >
    template < ECS_INT Filter >

  ITERATOR  CLASS::begin() {

    ITERATOR it(*this);
    while (! it.is_Valid())
      ++it;
    return std::move(it);
  }

  //!
  //! End
  //!
  template < TEMPLATE_ARGS >
    template < ECS_INT Filter >

  ITERATOR  CLASS::end() {

    ITERATOR it(*this);
    while (! it.is_Valid())
      ++it;
    return std::move(it);
  }

  //!------------------------------------------
  //!------------------------------------------

  //!
  //! ExtendPool
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void   DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::extendPool() {

    size_t i = m_pool.capacity();
    m_pool.reserve(m_pool.capacity() + BASE_SIZE);

    for (;i < m_pool.capacity(); ++i)
      m_pool[i].entry.nextFreeIndex = i;
  }


  //!
  //!  ReleaseObject
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void   DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::releaseObject(const ECS_INT index) {

    if (index < m_firstFreeEntry) {

      m_pool[index].entry.nextFreeIndex = m_firstFreeEntry;
      m_pool[index].entry.active = false;
      m_firstFreeEntry = index;
    }
    else {

      m_pool[index].entry.nextFreeIndex = m_pool[m_firstFreeEntry].entry.nextFreeIndex;
      m_pool[m_firstFreeEntry].entry.nextFreeIndex = index;
      m_pool[index].entry.active = false;
    }
    --m_activeEntryCount;
  }


  //!
  //! ReserveObjectMemory
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void   DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::reserveObjectMemory(size_t allocSize) {

    m_pool.reserve(allocSize);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_pool.capacity(); ++i)
      m_pool[i].entry.nextFreeIndex = i + 1;
  }


  //!
  //! Reset
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void   DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::reset(size_t allocSize) {

    m_pool.resize(allocSize);
    m_pool.shrink_to_fit();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_pool.capacity(); ++i)
      m_pool[i].entry.nextFreeIndex = i + 1;

    m_activeEntryCount = 0;
    m_firstFreeEntry = 0;
  }


  //!
  //! AddObject
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >
  template < typename ... Args >

  ECS_INT  DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::addNewObject(Args && ... args) {

    if (m_activeEntryCount >= m_pool.capacity())
      extendPool();

    const ECS_INT index = m_firstFreeEntry;
    HandleEntry& nHandle = m_pool[index].entry;

    m_firstFreeEntry = nHandle.nextFreeIndex;
    nHandle.nextFreeIndex = 0;
    nHandle.active = true;
    m_pool[index].data = Object(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    ++m_activeEntryCount;

    return index;
  }


  //!
  //!  AssignExistingObject
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void   DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::assignExistingObject(const ECS_INT index) {

    // Waiting for if constexpr
  }


  //!
  //! RemoveObject
  //!
  template < typename Object,
             bool Shared >

  void  DefaultManager<Object, Shared>::removeObject(const ECS_INT index) {

    //Waiting for if constexpr
    releaseObject(index);
  }
}
```

The most weird code seems to be the iterator and begin/end function. The whole code is [here](https://github.com/Celes-Eternal/ECS-Concept/tree/25fcd5d8aebeab05803ad8dbe2860ce27eb7a88b) if you want to see more.